# User Privacy and Data Security in Databases

Tags: database, security, privacy

Is there a way to design a database where users' profile data can be protected in case of system intrusion?

For example, private data may be valuable, even though it may not be directly related to financial transactions or passwords. [Phone numbers, email addresses, etc may be resold]

Is there a way to design a member-based website in which personal information is stored and manipulated by an authorized agent of the site. However, in this case the data could become devalued if the database was disconnected from the system.

I realize that most of user privacy and data concerns are mostly focused on the UI and preventing unauthorized users from accessing data that does not concern them. However, my question is how can user information be protected within the backend itself. I also realize that this is a case of loss of access of the data [and you can do anything reactive (technical wise)], but what I'm trying to discover is if something can be done proactively to dampen the blow.

My question is: how can personal data be protected, without taking away from the actual purpose of the data?

I can see a need for encrypting all information, but that would prevent groups from accessing the data related to the user. For example, you could encrypt userss zip codes with a private key, but how would you retain the ability to use the zip code's location information. [Maybe to make a claim to the user "these people may be near you"]

In this hypothetical situation, the attacker is given an exploited database. They can not use the originating system to manipulate the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you only access the users' information when they are logged in, you can use their password to decrypt data from the database. During this time, you could calculate a one-way hash from the zip code, for example, and store that unecrypted. But if you develop your database during the site's lifetime, you won't be able to update the information for old users who never log in. Maybe that isn't a problem in practice.

Comment: I like this answer, but surely there is a way to do a 1 way tranform without stripping out the meaning of the data. For example: a way of transforming the zipcode in such a way where you can compare two places and still tell if they are different locataions.

Comment: @monksy No. While you could apply a one way transform such as a hash, the space of zip addresses is so small that it's trivial to brute-force.

Comment: Yes, absolutely - that's what I was getting at. A user whose zip hashes to asdfghjkl is in the same zip code as other users with the same hashed zip. But you cannot expect asdfghjkm to be close, or you risk revealing private data.

Comment: You're right, you could brute force it, however ... that means that an attacker has to reverse a one-way transformation. [They would also have to figure out if you salted it, or attempt to create a probabilstic database of most likely matches] Additionally if it is bruteforced the only way the reversal is considered to be valid is if the attacker has evidence and context to the fields protected. You might be able to guess the majority of zip codes/post codes, but when you come down to the 80% of the sparse zip codes... there won't be as much evidence for them. [please see the question edit]

Comment: You would have to brute-force each user's password separately, though. But yes, adding a salt is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to presume that you're indicating an intruder has gained not only access to the machine, but any MySQL passwords as well.

With that being the case, the only solution I can think of would be to use an encrypted filesystem underneath the database.

Even there, though, you've still lost physical control of the device - so if the intruder has figured out the decryption key for the fs, you're still up the proverbial creek.

Another option would be to split the application so that the web site and database do not share the same system. And, of course, typically running the site with a read-only user is a Good Idea™ :)

Storing data in the database in a hashed or encrypted form is a good start, but you still need to have access to the decryption key, or it's going to be gobbledygook.

Ultimately, of course, the best way to secure the database is to prevent access - which is not a viable solution.

This is an issue that appears in the press periodically if/when a bank or store's customer list is accessed in an unauthorized form - the data is secure *only via* the interface/application: it's still in cleartext at some point underneath everything else.

Comment: I realize that you're up the creek when you lose access. However, my question was a "well how do you insure user privacy if all of the security layers are stripped off of the db" [i.e. the file system is decrypted etc] For example: if you have a fully protected database but raw data in the db [ignoring CCs and passwords] an sql injection attack will still circumvent the file system encryption, user accounts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Proper access controls are probably the most sensible approach in your example since you're not wanting to give up, e.g., the ability to sort or query against the fields in question.

Comment: Access controls won't mean anything if the database is nicked.